# Bypass product key

Tags: plugin-development

I have pro plugin from codecanyon with product key, which was used already. I couldn't use it in my new domain

Is there a way how to bypass the product key via FTP ?

Answer (score 1):

Product keys are usually only used for updates.

Have you tried using the plugin on another site to check if it works without the key?

If it doesn't work then it would probably be down to the licencing and you may need to buy a product key for the new site.
If that's the case then this question would essentially be asking how to steal.

Comment: The plugin is for single site use and lifetime subscription, I decomissioned the old domain and installed it in the new one but plugin still shows ''it is already installed in **** domain'' but in reality it is not as I uninstalled it, removed all contents from FTP. Author asked me to pay for support to reset the license which costs same price as new product , I disagreed. I am looking for ways how to bypass this through code change/ftp ...

Comment: I checked the plugin content all what is code related lines, I can see only: );
        
        private $default_settings = array(

          'item_purchase_code'=>'',

            'account_type'=> 'aliexpress',

            'use_custom_account'=>false,

            'account_data'=> array('aliexpress'=>array('appkey'=>'', 'trackingid'=>''), 

'admitad'=>array('cashback_url'=>'')),

Comment: You could search the plugin code for any messages that say it's not licenced and look to the code that triggers it. Somewhere along the line it will come down to true/false this plugin can be used or not.